# With radio not working, why it is more important to stay away from exactly class D airspace?

Tags: faa-regulations, landing, emergency, lost-communications, class-d-airspace

The instructions how to land when the radio is no longer working state as the first item "[stay away from the class D airspace](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/how-would-an-airplane-land-if-the-on-board-radio-breaks-down)".

Why is the class D specifically mentioned in these instructions? How it could be that A, B which "has the most stringent rules" and C are less a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The procedure in the linked answer assumes you're VFR. If you're in class A airspace, that means you must be IFR, and there are specific (and somewhat different) procedures for IFR flights that lose radio communications--which may include landing at a class A/B/C airport. VFR pilots without radios should stick to class D/E/G airports, which are a lot more plentiful anyway. Most B/C airports are ringed by D/E/G airports, so unless you lose your radios while already inside class B/C airspace, those wouldn't be very logical options anyway.

Comment: This answer confuses me.  "VFR pilots without radios should stick to class D/E airports, which are a lot more plentiful anyway"  -- why not a Class G airport?  And why lump Class E in with Class D -- you don't need to talk to anyone to land at surface-level Class E, unless the weather is bad enough that you want to request SVFR.  Wouldn't it be more logical to say "VFR pilots without radios should stick to class G/E airports, which are a lot more plentiful anyway"?

Comment: @quietflyer I’ve updated to say D/E/G.  Personally, I’d rather use a D airport because there will be someone watching me land and, if there’s something more wrong than just lost comms (maybe I lost comms because I’m on fire!), call fire/rescue immediately.

Answer (score 8):

I think you are mis-interpreting the answer, you should remain outside Class-D *until the flow of traffic can be acertained*. If you lose comms outside of a Class-B or Class-C, you should not enter that airspace, instead divert to a Class-D or E airport if possible. If you are already inside the B/C airspace, continue, but don't enter. Class-A is different, as it is not surrounding airports and you can fly IFR after you've gotten your clearance with lost comms.

The original question links to the [AIM, Chapter 4, Section 2-13](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/media/aim.pdf), read that and see if it clears things up.

Comment: FYI, Europe has a few airports in surface class A airspace, and some low-ish airways are class A too. Lots of different models outside the US on how/where to use the various classes.

Comment: @StephenSprunk While true, the answer which was linked to in the original questions is about US/FAA procedures.