# What are the procedures for radio malfunction

Tags: radio, radio-navigation

I was reading this question [Do airline pilots ever risk not hearing communication directed to them specifically, from traffic controllers?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/62122/do-airline-pilots-ever-risk-not-hearing-communication-directed-to-them-specifica) and there is a answer mentioning radio malfunction

> If it's a real radio problem, there are procedures for both sides to follow to keep everyone safe.

How do pilots / ATC work together if radio does not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would an airplane land if the on-board radio breaks down?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/how-would-an-airplane-land-if-the-on-board-radio-breaks-down/3798)

Comment: @Jamiec thank you; could not find the question you linked.