# EASA procedures for radio/comm failure under VFR rules

Tags: visual-flight-rules, radio

Trying to find the VFR communication failure procedure in EASA, but can't find anything clear enough, maybe someone have a link for clear instructions for that procedure?

I want to figure out what should I do in case of comm failure under VFR rules when -

- I am in uncontrolled airspace? (G or vfr in E - controlled but communication not required) can I continue my flight? As I am not required to have two way communication (at least in the Czech Republic) and just somehow deal with the destination airport? Or should I land ASAP ?
- What should I do if I am crossing controlled airspace? Continue with my clearance? Or leave the controlled airspace asap?
- In case of flight into a controlled airport and communication failure just before the traffic Circuit, what to do? Continue to the circuit and hope someone will understand that I am without a radio and use lights?

I checked all the VFR manuals I found but didn't find any clear instructions, just "squak 7600 and land in the nearest suitable airfield" but it feel too simplified for me...

Comment: Closely related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/3794/how-would-an-airplane-land-if-the-on-board-radio-breaks-down

Comment: @Jamiec, thanks! but from what I see in the answer it's related to the FAA, I believe that there should be some differences between the FAA procedures and the EASA ones, am I wrong ?

Comment: I don't think they're materially different. I wrote that answer with reference to an FAA publications but I fly in the UK and would follow much the same procedures (even though we're no longer EASA!)

Comment: Much of that answer was also written with reference to https://www.cfinotebook.net/notebook/flight-hazards-and-safety/lost-communication

Comment: Surely it matters *what sort of* controlled airspace you are in?  Certainly it does in the US, there's a lot of controlled airspace (namely Class E) that you can fly in VFR *without talking to anyone*.  Question strikes me as being overly broad-- but maybe it wouldn't to someone more familiar with EASA-- ??

Comment: Actually to put a finer point on it-- Class E airspace *is controlled airspace* in the US, and that's surely true for EASA too.  Please edit the question.  (Pertains to content after first "bullet" point.)  Way too many people think the definition of "controlled airspace" is "I have to talk to a controller to go there."  That's wrong.  In the US, controlled airspace is *anything other than Class G*, and I suspect it's the same in EASA-land too.

Comment: @quietflyer, my understanding is that outside of the USA Class E is relatively rare—at least low-level.