# Is there a designated air-to-air HF frequency in the USA?

Tags: faa-regulations, radio-communications, frequency

Suppose I'm flying somewhere over the middle of the United States, happily <strike>telling stories</strike> exchanging important flight-related information with another aircraft on 122.75, the designated VHF air-to-air frequency.

Now let's say that the other aircraft has reached the limit of VHF transmission range, and I still have more to say.  We're both HF equipped.

**Is there a designated HF frequency available for air-to-air use in the USA?**

Comment: If you're telling stories, the amateur radio service is intended for that, has significant swaths of HF spectrum, and airborne use is permitted in the US. ([Previous question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/65364/are-ham-radio-contacts-allowed-from-inside-an-airplane))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reviewing 47 CFR 87.187 - FCC, Safety & Special Radio Services, Aviation Services, Aircraft Stations, Frequencies, it does not appear that the FCC has designated a dedicated air-to-air HF frequency. All the air-to-air frequencies in the regulation are in the VHF range. Sections bb through hh.