# Why do some nations allow the usage of hand held devices and some not throughout the landing till the take off

Tags: safety

After going through this [site](http://www.howtogeek.com/194019/yes-you-can-use-electronics-during-takeoff-and-landing-what-you-need-to-know/) I am still not clear as to why do some nations do not allow the use of hand held device's especially  cell phones for making calls or texting but for gaming or reading during take off or landing or throughout the flight.

although the difference lies in network usage but still the device is ON and still may cause disturbance to the onboard equipment like navigation or communication. Then what's the point in allowing for gaming or reading throughout the flight.

I have seen some reports that claim they don't cause disturbance and some say they do.

Comment: different companies different standards and practices.

Comment: duplicate? http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2021/1467

Comment: @Federico thanks for pointing out because I could not see any question when posting it from the Android mobile browser