Does using a Starlink mini in a plane's cabin pose any danger to the plane?
Does using a Starlink mini in a plane's cabin pose any danger to the plane? I am mostly interested in commercial planes.

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2021/why-arent-cell-phones-allowed-to-be-used-in-aircraft

Why do you think there is more than zero danger?

You'd likely have problems picking up a signal inside the cabin.  That's why the airplane's Starlink antenna is mounted on the outside.

@MichaelHall Thanks, good point: I've added Would a Starlink mini placed inside a plane's cabin be able to get Internet connection? to focus on that aspect.

In short
This transceiver could be dangerous aboard an aircraft, not because of its 4W transmitter but because the antenna is a hi-gain antenna concentrating this small power within a narrow cone of 3.5°, where it has the same effect as if it were a huge 6.6kW equally distributed.
However this is only a possibility as the transceiver is likely prevented to transmit without the satellite in sight, i.e. when the antenna is not pointed outside. When the bean is targeting a satellite, the level of radiations in other directions is unlikely to interfere with avionics.

The Starlink transceiver itself
When the transceiver is powered, there are different points to consider:

The device uplink transmitter works in Ku band at about 14GHz. The RF amplifier maximum power of a Starlink transceiver, specified in the FCC license request, is 4W. This seems to be the same as the maximum EIRP power of an old 2G/GSM-1800 cell phone. However this comparison is misleading, the two power numbers are not comparable:

RF power is measured in the RF amplifier, before the antenna.

EIRP power is the one effectively radiated by the antenna in the beam direction.


EIRP power is the product of the RF power by the antenna gain. The flat array antenna has a theoretical gain of 35dBi (calculated here as 32.8dBd which is the same, comparable antenna). It is a beamforming device, steering and concentrating the power in a cone of 3.5° centered on the satellite direction:

4W is 6 dBW (I use this dB converter)
Adding the gain 35dBi gives 41dBi
41 dBi is more than 12kW, but half this power (3dB) is lost in the system
This gives 6.6kW EIRP. This is a lot and definitely not comparable to the 4W EIRP of a GSM cell phone.


The Ku band 12GHz downlink receiver also radiates spurious signals on unknown frequencies, depending on its technology. One cannot evaluate this point easily.

The Wi-Fi access point transmits on the Wi-Fi bands with an EIRP of 100mW on 2.4GHz and 200mW on 5GHz, this is not a concern.


Equipment resistance to interferences, including avionics
Reading research documents on PED alleged interference with avionics, you see FCC and FAA (see below) have adopted this position: Usual PED are a priori innocuous for avionics equipment. This is based on the fact all commercial products can be approved only if they satisfy some obligations:

They mustn't radiate more than a small level of spurious signals or harmonics.

They must be able to work with spurious signals from other devices, limited in power as stated above.

They must be able to cope with other approved devices using their maximum approved power.


Operator rules for usual PED
PED rules are mostly operators rules, the regulator provides a guidance to establish the rules, this guidance is mostly asking for a test before allowing unusual equipment use aboard.
Usually operators forbid using the device during the critical phases (when the PED light is on), and allow them in cruise. However a hi-gain antenna is not a usual equipment.
Hi-gain antenna case
Both Starlink devices and avionics devices are approved as meeting the interference obligations. Starlink lists these obligations:

Therefore, Starlink’s in-motion operations, including for vessels, must accept any interference received from both current and future services authorized in the band – even if such interference causes undesirable operations for Starlink Services and its customers. Starlink in-motion Services must not cause harmful interference to any authorized service in the band, whether licensed or not.

However the unusual hi-gain antenna would require a dedicated test by the operator before allowing its use. This is unlikely this test has been already conducted.
You can compare a gain antenna with a laser light: Even with a limited power, the light beam can dangerous due to the small size of the beam. Similarly, you cannot guarantee the antenna panel will be directed to the outside, a configuration where only a small signal, likely acceptable, is directed to the avionics.
The way the array works is not fully described. However to meet power density constraints protecting GSO (geostationary) satellites from the signals of the lower NGSO (non-GSO) satellites, NGSO user equipment uses approved EIRP masks (in license request), it is likely the user transmitter won't transmit at a significant level before it finds the direction of the NGSO satellite currently covering its cell, hence it may be prevented to transmit when not pointed to the outside of the aircraft. That's likely, but still a a supposition.
The crew may not be familiar with amplifier power and EIRP difference. For my own safety and the safety of others, I would ask both Starlink customer service and the operator before using the device within an aircraft.
FAA and FCC view on PED in 2013: No restriction a priori
A 2013 FAA document, now cancelled, summarized the regulation:

FCC doesn't prohibit the use of PED, including transmitters, including during critical phases of flight.

FAA doesn't prohibit it either, and it ready to help operators to test PED. In the end it says PED rules must be defined by each operator.


From FAA Notice 8900.240, Recommendations on Expanding the Use of Portable Electronic Devices During Flight, 2013:

Under the current regulatory environment, the operator is still responsible for determining which PEDs may be used on its airplanes. Each operator’s PED policy determines what types of devices may be used during which phase(s) of flight. Crewmembers are responsible for ensuring passenger compliance with an airplane operator’s PED policy. Current guidance allows broad use of non-transmitting PEDs during non-critical phases of flight without detailed study of specific PEDs.


However, if an operator wishes to expand its PED use allowance, FAA policy and guidance is in place to allow PED use, with the proper testing and analysis, during any phase of flight.


Operators have been hesitant to deviate from current FAA guidance, as there has been no clear direction on methods to demonstrate an equivalent level of safety when expanding PED use into critical phases of flight.


FCC regulations also govern certain aspects of PED usage. The FCC has established rules for radio transmitters and consumer electronics to minimize the risk of harmful interference to other users of the airwaves. FCC rules, with a few notable exceptions, do not prohibit use of radio
transmitters or consumer electronics aboard airplanes.

As of 2013 several studies, including by NASA, had already analyzed many events where PED were suspected to cause critical avionics problems (like in Personal Electronic Devices and Their Interference With Aircraft Systems from 2001), still FCC/FAA didn't see any problems allowing their use in fight, after a test. This document was likely replaced and amended, but I cannot find a current equivalent, so it is safer to ignore the conclusion.

Smartphones contain batteries, and batteries sometimes catch fire.  Occasionally that happens on a plane.  Cabin crew know how to put the fire out.
Starlink Mini has a power supply that would need to be plugged in.  There is no battery.  So it's not likely to have a battery fire.
The Starlink Mini is over 6 kg, so it would do a lot more damage than a smartphone if you drop it on the pilot's toes when they walk by.

Thanks, the Starlink Mini is 1.1 kg. (https://www.starlink.com/specifications?spec=5). Still painful though :) you forgot head injuries when I'll brandish it to try to get a signal.
